# Row selection not working in primefaces (5.3) data table when the lazy loading is implemented, but it works without lazy loading

Tags: jsf, primefaces, lazy-loading

**This is my data table:**

```
<h:form id="eventListForm">
                <p:contextMenu id="eventDataTableContextMenu" for="datalist">  
                <p:menuitem value="#{myBundle.Create}" onclick="document.getElementById('eventListForm:createButton').click();" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
                <p:menuitem value="#{myBundle.View}" onclick="document.getElementById('eventListForm:viewButton').click();" icon="ui-icon-search"/>
                <p:menuitem value="#{myBundle.Edit}" onclick="document.getElementById('eventListForm:editButton').click();" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
                <p:menuitem value="#{myBundle.Delete}" onclick="document.getElementById('eventListForm:deleteButton').click();" icon="ui-icon-trash"/>
            </p:contextMenu>
            <p:dataTable id="datalist"
                         value="#{eventController.lazyModel}"
                         var="item"
                         rowKey="#{item.eventId}"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                         rows="10"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         selection="#{eventController.selected}"
                         lazy="true">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form:createButton,@form:viewButton,@form:editButton,@form:deleteButton,@form:eventDataTableContextMenu"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form:createButton,@form:viewButton,@form:editButton,@form:deleteButton,@form:eventDataTableContextMenu"/>
                <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update="@form:createButton @form:viewButton @form:editButton @form:deleteButton"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" onsuccess="document.getElementById('eventListForm:viewButton').click();"/>
```

**This is the controller:**

```
 public class EventController {

        IEventService eventService;
        List<EventDTO> items;
        private EventDTO selected;
        private Integer priorityIdSelected;

        private LazyDataModel<EventDTO> lazyModel;

        public void init() {
            //items = eventService.getAll();
            lazyModel = new EventLazyLoader(eventService);
        }


public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Event Selected", ((EventDTO) event.getObject()).getEventId().toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

**This is the lazy loader implementation:**

```
public class EventLazyLoader extends LazyDataModel<EventDTO> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<EventDTO> datasource;

    public EventLazyLoader(IEventService eventServiceImpl) {
        this.datasource = eventServiceImpl.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public EventDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for(EventDTO event : datasource) {
            if(event.getEventId().equals(rowKey))
                return event;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(EventDTO event) {
        return event.getEventId();
    }

    @Override
    public List<EventDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        List<EventDTO> data = new ArrayList<EventDTO>();
          //filter
        for(EventDTO event : datasource) {
            boolean match = true;
            if (filters != null) {
                for (Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    try {
                        String filterProperty = it.next();
                        Object filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                        String fieldValue = String.valueOf(event.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(event));
                        if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue.toString())) {
                            match = true;
                        } else {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        match = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(match) {
                data.add(event);
            }
        }

        //sort
        if(sortField != null) {
            Collections.sort(data, new EventLazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
        }

        //rowCount
        int dataSize = data.size();
        this.setRowCount(dataSize);

        //paginate
        if(dataSize > pageSize) {
            try {
                return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
            }
        }
        else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The controller also have a the **items** List (java.util.List  ) if I use this list as a data for the data list the row selection works without any problem, it seems that the problem is the lazy loading, but I don't have any idea why this is happening.

By the way thanks a lot for all the hints and help that someone can give me.

Comment: I don't see anything about `onRowSelect` You should look over the `primfaces` showcase for lazy loading carefully.

Comment: Thats the matter I created the lazy loading as is in the primefaces show case: http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml, but can't find where is the error.

Comment: Like I said, I don't see anything in your code about `onRowSelect`. If row select is not working, perhaps you need an `onRowSelect`. Looking into that is my best suggestion.

Comment: I just added the method in the post at the controller, forgot about it when I created the question.

Comment: Well, if it still doesn't work, there is not much I can do. I can't compile your code because it is incomplete. I have confidence that if I test the showcase code it will work fine, so there is no way I can debug your code. Firstly, because your example is incomplete, and secondly and mostly, because that's not what this forum is for.

Comment: Well I'm not sure about it but at first I deployed the project on JBoss 7.1 and it worked ok, now I changed to tomcat 7, and isn't working, but not sure that could be a possible cause.

Comment: I suppose you should debug it and make sure the the `onRowSelect` is being called.

Comment: Finally I solved this problem, The problem was a logic error in the LazyDataModel specifically in the "getRowData(String rowKey)" method.

If someone read this and need some help I will be happy of helping you.

Comment: Why are you using lazy data model, when you call `eventServiceImpl.getAll();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem, The problem was a logic error in the LazyDataModel implementation specifically in the "getRowData(String rowKey)" method.
In the comment **"Error here"** the problem was that in the primefaces showcase, the example uses the equals() method to compare, my problem was that I tried to compare for equality one Integer (the id of my dto) with the string value obtained from the row selection, so I parse that string and finally compare the integer values (a silly mistake if you think about it)

```
public class EventLazyLoader extends LazyDataModel<EventDTO> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EventLazyLoader.class);

    private List<EventDTO> datasource;

    public EventLazyLoader(IEventService eventServiceImpl) {
        this.datasource = eventServiceImpl.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public EventDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
        int intRowKey = Integer.parseInt(rowKey);
        for(EventDTO event : datasource) {
            if(event.getEventId() == intRowKey) {//Error here
                return event;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(EventDTO event) {
        return event.getEventId();
    }

    @Override
    public List<EventDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters) {
        List<EventDTO> data = new ArrayList<EventDTO>();
          //filter
        for(EventDTO event : datasource) {
            boolean match = true;
            if (filters != null) {
                for (Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    try {
                        String filterProperty = it.next();
                        Object filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);
                        String fieldValue = String.valueOf(event.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(event));
                        if(filterValue == null || fieldValue.startsWith(filterValue.toString())) {
                            match = true;
                        } else {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        match = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(match) {
                data.add(event);
            }
        }

        //sort
        if(sortField != null) {
            Collections.sort(data, new EventLazySorter(sortField, sortOrder));
        }

        //rowCount
        int dataSize = data.size();
        this.setRowCount(dataSize);

        //paginate
        if(dataSize > pageSize) {
            try {
                return data.subList(first, first + pageSize);
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return data.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
            }
        }
        else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better add full solution. Also this is a common approach for LazyLoading in all the datatable or for each the different datatable you have to make a class

Comment: I am facing one issue in primefaces datatable lazy loading, can you help?